# Steam (using wine) starting civ 5 on the wrong screen

Tags: wine, screen, steam

I have my left screen set as primary screen in ubuntu (unity) and most things just do what they are supposed to do when they are fullscreen. They run on my primary screen.

But for some reason when I launch civ 5 from steam (using wine, not the new beta) it fullscreens to my second (smaller) screen.

How can I make this game appear fullscreen on my primarry screen?

I am using the  fglrx-updates driver that ubuntu provides.

Comment: I have pretty much the same problem. The only workaround I've found so far is to temporarily disable the second output, start Civ5, change game resolution to a value that's not supported by the smaller screen and restart the game. That pretty much works most of times. Whenever I start the game on a dual screen setup, the smaller screen is chosen as output and the game resolution is reduced automatically.

Comment: I mean no insult, but I just want to let you know that Civilization 5 is now available on Linux, natively, through Steam :D

Answer (score 1):

Civ 5 has a version for Linux.  Try installing Steam for Linux and then installing Civ 5 there.  You may actually get better performance this way too!